# Is there a way to randomize css classes in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, css-selectors

Is there a way to randomize css classes and update them in html and js files?

Something like gmail have, on every request some classes are different.

[image: gmail classes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Modules

This practice is now known as "CSS Modules" and is becoming more widely adopted with the popularity of Webpack. The concept is to transform (hash) CSS selectors into unique class names, to ensure that there are no collisions of styles between modules.

The [css-loader module](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#css-modules) for Webpack has a `modules` option which enables this feature. It is commonly used with React, where you assign class names in your markup via a JS object made available by importing the CSS file, e.g.

```
import styles from './style.css
```

If that CSS file has a selector, e.g. `.sidebar`, it is applied in the markup via

```
className={styles.sidebar} // JSX
```

Webpack will hash the class name and matcing selector to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: How to do it without `className={styles.sidebar} // JSX` ? Could it be done through just html? Its not like I cant use react or vue, I am just asking